# Secondary window without slot

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, signals-slots

I would like to create a secondary windows for the user's settings, so in my class QMainWindow, I call an object Settings like this:

```
self.settingsAction = QtGui.QAction('Préférences', self)
self.settingsAction.triggered.connect(lambda: Settings(self))
```

Then, I build my Settings class:

```py
class Settings():

    """ Méthode pour effectuer les réglages du programme
    par l'utilisateur """

    def __init__(self, parent):

        #TODO: faire de cette fenêtre l'enfant de la fenêtre principale
        #On crée une fenêtre secondaire

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()
        self.connexion()
        self.etablirSlots()


    def connexion(self):

        self.parent.options.beginGroup("Watching")
        pathes = self.parent.options.allKeys()
        if pathes:
            for each_key in pathes:
                self.list_pathes.addItem(self.parent.options.value(each_key))
        self.parent.options.endGroup()


    def etablirSlots(self):

        self.add_directory_button.clicked.connect(self.addPath)
        self.rm_directory_button.clicked.connect(self.removePath)


    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.fen_settings = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.parent.fen_settings.setWindowTitle('Préférences')

        #http://cyp1973.blogspot.fr/2009/05/qt-resource-file.html
        #On crée un QListWidget pr présenter les pathes
        self.list_pathes = QtGui.QListWidget()

        #On crée un titre pour la zone des pathes à surveiller
        label_directories = QtGui.QLabel("Dossiers surveillés :")

        #On crée les boutons d'ajout et de retrait d'un path
        self.add_directory_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Ajouter")
        self.rm_directory_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Enlever")

        #On crée une grille pr gérer la disposition des widgets
        grid_settings = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid_settings.addWidget(label_directories, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        grid_settings.addWidget(self.list_pathes, 1, 0, 2, 1)
        grid_settings.addWidget(self.add_directory_button, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        grid_settings.addWidget(self.rm_directory_button, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.parent.fen_settings.setLayout(grid_settings)
        self.parent.fen_settings.show()


    def removePath(self):

        """ Slot pour enlever un path à surveiller
        de la conf """
        print("coucou")

        #try:
        path = self.list_pathes.selectedItems()[0].text()
        print(path)

        #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484699/
        #pyqt4-remove-item-widget-from-qlistwidget
        #On efface le path de la liste visible
        item = self.list_pathes.takeItem(self.list_pathes.currentRow())
        del item
        #except IndexError:
            #print("Aucun path sélectionné")
            #pass


    def addPath(self):

        """ Slot pour ajouter un path à surveiller à la conf """

        #TODO: vérifier que le path à ajouter n'est pas déjà dans la liste

        #On crée une boite de dialogue pr choisir le path à ajouter
        #et on ajoute le path à la liste visible
        path = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self.parent.fen_settings, 'Open file', '/home')
        self.list_pathes.addItem(path)
```

But the two buttons of my secondary window seem to not be connected to my slots. Everythin is fine except that, and I checked, if I use this class alone, without passing the QMainWindow in argument, it works perfectly.

Would you have an idea about why these slots are not connected ? Maybe the signals are not emitted properly ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you aren't passing the parent to the buttons, this is a working version of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Settings(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Settings, self).__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent

        self.setWindowTitle(u'Préférences')

        self.list_pathes = QtGui.QListWidget(self)

        self.label_directories = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label_directories.setText(u"Dossiers surveillés :")

        self.rm_directory_button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.rm_directory_button.setText(u"Enlever")
        self.rm_directory_button.clicked.connect(self.removePath)

        self.add_directory_button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.add_directory_button.setText(u"Ajouter")
        self.add_directory_button.clicked.connect(self.addPath)

        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_directories, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.list_pathes, 2, 0, 2, 2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.rm_directory_button, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.add_directory_button, 2, 2, 1, 1)

        self.show()    
    #    self.connexion()

    def connexion(self):
        self.parent.options.beginGroup("Watching")
        pathes = self.parent.options.allKeys()
        if pathes:
            for each_key in pathes:
                self.list_pathes.addItem(self.parent.options.value(each_key))

        self.parent.options.endGroup()

    def removePath(self):
        try:
            path = self.list_pathes.selectedItems()[0].text()
            item = self.list_pathes.takeItem(self.list_pathes.currentRow())
            del item

        except IndexError:
            print(u"Aucun path sélectionné")

    def addPath(self):
        path = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Open file', '/home')
        self.list_pathes.addItem(path)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.settingsAction = QtGui.QAction(u'Préférences', self)
        self.settingsAction.triggered.connect(lambda: Settings(self))

        self.toolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(self)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.settingsAction)

        self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.ToolBarArea(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea), self.toolBar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys

    app  = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Oh, I'm such a dummy. You are right, it works perfectly. I forgot to herit from QDialog, and to give the parent to the buttons. Thanks a lot.